# Mock BindingResult in unit test case when user does not exist

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm very new to Mockito and Junit. I'm working on creating test case for forgot password workflow. Below is the code for controller and test. Could anyone tell me how should I test on bindingresult?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/public/forgotPassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView sendforgetPasswordLink(@ModelAttribute ForgetPasswordBean forgetPasswordBean,BindingResult result, HttpSession session) {

    BreadCrumbBuilder.addLinktoBreadCrumb(session, new Link(Constants.FORGET_PASSWORD_TITLE, "/user/public/forgotPassword", Constants.GROUP_USER, 0));

    Map<String, String> breadCrumbs = HomePageController.setupInitialBreadCrumbs(session);
    breadCrumbs.put(Constants.FORGET_PASSWORD_TITLE,    "/user/public/forgotPassword"); 
    session.setAttribute(SessionAttributes.BREAD_CRUMBS,breadCrumbs);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(); 
    mav.addObject("displayTitle", Constants.FORGET_PASSWORD_TITLE);

    PublicUser user = publicUserService.findPublicUserByEmail(forgetPasswordBean.getEmail().toLowerCase());
    if(user == null) {
        result.reject("email", "An account does not exist for this email.");
        mav.setViewName("publicuser/forgetPassword.jsp");
        return mav;
    }

    String randomId = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    user.setTempId(randomId);
    mailService.sendForgetPasswordLink(user);
    publicUserService.savePublicUser(user);
    String msg = "Password reset instructions have been sent to your email.";

    mav.addObject("msg", msg);
    mav.setViewName("message.jsp");
    return mav;
}
```

This is test I created so far

```
@Test
public void TestForgetPasswordForNoUserFound() throws Exception {

    final String input_email = "abc@test.com";

    ForgetPasswordBean  forgetPasswordBean = new ForgetPasswordBean();
    forgetPasswordBean.setEmail(input_email);

    PublicUser daoUser = new PublicUser();
    daoUser.setEmail(input_email);

    when(mockPublicUserService.findPublicUserByEmail(input_email)).thenReturn(null);
    when(mockBindingResult.hasErrors()).thenReturn(true);

    final ModelAndView modelAndView = controller.sendforgetPasswordLink(forgetPasswordBean, mockBindingResult, mockHttpSession);
    ModelMap modelMap = modelAndView.getModelMap();


    assertEquals("An account does not exist for this email.", modelMap.get(mockBindingResult));
    assertEquals("publicuser/forgetPassword.jsp", modelAndView.getViewName());
    assertModelAttributeValue(modelAndView, "displayTitle", Constants.FORGET_PASSWORD_TITLE);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is verify behavior of your `BindingResult` by checking that the `reject` method was called.

Basically instead of

```
assertEquals("An account does not exist for this email.", modelMap.get(mockBindingResult));
```

You can do the following

```
Mockito.verify(mockBindingResult).reject("email", "An account does not exist for this email.");
```

And that way you can verify that the method was called.

Comment: I ran the test. It failed due to NullPointerException. The trace is too long...so i can't post here. Do you know what caused this failure? Thanks!

Comment: You can post at least the line where it says "NullPointerException".

Comment: 'java.lang.NullPointerException
 at gov.hhs.cdelr.web.PublicUserController.sendforgetPasswordLink(PublicUserController.java:410)
 at gov.hhs.cdelr.web.PublicUserControllerTest.TestForgetPasswordForNoUserFound(PublicUserControllerTest.java:104)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)'

Comment: PublicUserControll‌​er.java:410 is "result.reject("email", "An account does not exist for this email.");"

Comment: This must have been failing before. Because the changed I proposed is only in the assertions at the end of `TestForgetPasswordForNoUserFound` method

Comment: Yes. It's not because of the change. Sorry, I should have clarified. I just want to add a follow-up question. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: I'd recommend you to ask a new question in a different post and we'll be glad to answer it. And if this was the correct answer for you please mark it as Accepted by checking the mark.

Comment: I did. Could you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057234/nullpointerexecption-failure-when-creating-unit-test-for-java-spring-controller Thanks!